# SQL INNER JOIN Query not working on 2nd table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables which I combine via INNER JOIN statement in SQL ...

```
Heinz
- Column id
- column carID
- column description

Wurst
- Column carID
- column applesort
```

```
SELECT * 
FROM Heinz 
INNER JOIN Wurst ON Heinz.carID = Wurst.carID 
WHERE description = 'Test' AND Wurst.applesort = 'Cox'
```

It doesn't work ... **There is no error but I get a blank result**

But when I delete the

> AND Wurst.applesort = 'COX'

it works ... So I think there is a problem with the 2nd table ...

Can you help me?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: Oh sorry ... I get a blank result ...

Comment: When you remove the applesort = 'COX' are there any actual rows in the returned results where applesort does actually equal 'Cox'?

Comment: are you sure you are joining on the right field ?

Answer (score 1):

If you run a query:

```
SELECT * FROM Wurst WHERE Wurst.applesort= 'COX'
```

does it produce results?

If not, then it explains why you don't get results from the joined query.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you have no results because, with your conditions in the WHERE clause

```
WHERE description = 'Test' AND Wurst.applesort = 'Cox'
```

there're no rows satisfying both conditions. 
That would explain why, removing the condition `'Wurst.applesort = 'Cox'`, your query works. Did you check your data before using a INNER JOIN?